# Display AJAX success response in Table

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

How to display the value in table..I am not able to display the value.In ajax i've sent all the value and after retrieving the records from database. I've to display the result in table

Output is

```
 [{"ID":"15","patient_name":"Sangeeta","patient_email":"sangeetha@gmail.com","gender":"Female","age":"26","address":"Jayanagar","city":"Bangalore","laboratory_name":"Anand","laboratory_address":"bsk","laboratory_place":"bengaluru","referral_pat_id":"18","active":"1","created_on":"2017-06-13"}]
```

How to retrieve each value

AJAX Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    alert(rowid);
    console.log(rowid);
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'url', //Here you will fetch records 
        data :  'id='+ rowid, //Pass $id
        success : function(resp){
          alert(resp);
         var trHTML = '';
                    $.each(resp, function (i, userData) {
                        for (i = 0; i < resp.UserData.length; i++) {
        alert(trHTML);

                            trHTML +=
                                '<tr><td>'
                                + resp.userData[i].ID
                                + '</td><td>'
                                + resp.userData[i].patient_name
                                + '</td><td>'
                                + resp.userData[i].patient_email 
                                + '</td></tr>';
                        }
                    });
                    $('#tBody').append(trHTML);
        }
    });
  });
 });
```

Controller

```
 public function fetch_records()
 {
    print_r($_POST);
    $this->load->model('Physician_confirm_m');

    $id = $_POST['id']; //escape string
    print_r($id);
    $result=$this->Physician_confirm_m->fetch_history_records($id);
    echo json_encode($result);      
}
```

Model

```
 public function fetch_history_records($id)
 {
 $this->db->where('referral_pat_id',$id);
 $this->db->from('referral_confirmation_details');
 $q = $this->db->get();
 return $q->result();
 }
```

HTML

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info disablebtn" style="text-align: center;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="<?php echo $post->referral_patient_id;?>"><i class="fa fa-history" aria-hidden="true"></i><strong> HISTORY</strong></button>

<div class="modal-body"> 
      <table>

        <tbody id="tBody"></tbody>
      </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to create server side datatable ...?

Comment: On button click i am sending the row id and displaying it in the bootstrap modal in the table format...But i am not able to retrieve each object

Comment: where is yout html structure of displaying all records in that table. may be there is some issue

Comment: put e.preventDefault() on your click event

Comment: yeah but still i am not getting output..i have updated my HTML table where the values to be displayed

Comment: @user5370838 Json is not valid. comma missing after "city": "Bangalore"

Comment: show your button where you click and I am agree with Nathan Srivi's comment

Comment: Sorry i have edited it before...i have updated the button

Comment: where is datatable jquery code, according to me, datatable itself manage page, offset data, right?

Comment: I am still not using datatable since i didnt get the output to display

Comment: It seems to be you are making `print_r($_POST);` in your Controller. That will make the invalid JSON output. Comment it. And it will be good practice if you can set the output header in to `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

You can do in another way to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');

    console.log(rowid);
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'url', //Here you will fetch records 
        data :  'id='+ rowid, //Pass $id
        success : function(resp){
           var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(resp);
           $('#tBody').append(obj.ajaxPage);
        }
    });
  });
 });
```

In Your Controller should be like

```
public function fetch_records()
 {

    $this->load->model('Physician_confirm_m');

    $id = $_POST['id']; //escape string

    $data['result']=$this->Physician_confirm_m->fetch_history_records($id);

    $result['ajaxPage'] = $this->load->view('pages/result_table', $data, true);
    echo json_encode($result);      
}
```

result_table view page should be

```
<?php if($result){ foreach($result as $row){ ?>
<tr>
 <td><?=$row['ID']?></td>
  <td><?=$row['patient_name'];?></td>
  <td><?=$row['patient_email'];?></td>;
</tr>
<?php 
   } 
}?>
```

Comment: I tried this one @Eswaran Arumugam.. But i am getting error like {"ajaxPage":"\r\n\r\n\r\n

Comment: just put console.log(resp) above  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(resp) and check it.

Comment: In my Html Table i am getting this Undefined variable: result and in my console i am getting the error ["result"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
{"ajaxPage":"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang=\"en\">\r\n<head>\r\n  <title>Search<\/title>\r\n  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\r\n  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\r\n